# Break while loop only when all conditions in for loop are met

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, break

I would like to break a `while` loop only when all of the "bots" are upright. (*These bots being referred to are mini USB robots).

`.upRight()` returns `true` when a bot is standing and `false` when not.

```
public static boolean checkSomething() throws ... {

        while (true) {

            for (i = 0; i < bots; i++) { // bots = 2
                if (!theMainBots[i].isUpright()) {
                    ...
                    Thread.sleep(1000); 
                } 
                else {
                    return true;

                }
            }
        }
```

The issue I'm facing, is that if the `isUpright()` method returns true for the first "bot", then all other bots are left unchecked and may return `false`. The intention is to wait for the user to place the bot in an upright position before proceeding.

Comment: Why `while(true)`?

Comment: @ernest_k Sorry, I'm quite new to Java. What's wrong with doing so?

Comment: *FYI:* [OP has said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53050909/break-while-loop-only-when-all-conditions-in-for-loop-are-met/53050992?noredirect=1#comment93001756_53050971): *"It's more than possible for the bot to fall over again."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check all the bots first, then act on the result. Don't try to act on the result inside the check loop.

Also, since the code doesn't return until all bots are upright, the method is misnamed and shouldn't return a value.

```
public static void waitUntilAllUpright() throws InterruptedException {
    for (;;) { // forever loop
        boolean allUpright = true;
        for (i = 0; i < bots; i++) {
            if (! theBots[i].isUpright()) {
                allUpright = false;
                break;
            } 
        }
        if (allUpright)
            return;
        System.out.println("Please ensure I'm upright");
        Thread.sleep(500); 
    } // loop back to check all bots again
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to wait until the user makes the bot upright you could change the `if` to a `while`:

```
while (true) {
     for (i = 0; i < bots; i++) { // bots = 2
         while(!theBots[i].isUpright()) {
             System.out.println("Please ensure I'm upright");
             Thread.sleep(500); 
         } 
     }               
     return true;     
}
```

This will loop through each element in the `Array` and while any given bot is not upright, it will loop and sleep until the bot is turned upright. In which case, you do not need to `while(true)` loop:

```
public static boolean checkUpright() throws InterruptedException {
      for (i = 0; i < bots; i++) { // bots = 2
         while(!theBots[i].isUpright()) {
             System.out.println("Please ensure I'm upright");
             Thread.sleep(500); 
         } 
     }               
     return true;    
}
```

Comment: You can get rid of the outer while loop

Comment: @DaneWhite Correct. I was already working on an edit. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Without more detailed specification, if `isUpright()` can transition from `false` to `true` over time, it is feasible that it can transition the other way too, so by the time you get to the last bot, the first bot may have fallen again. Not getting into the issues of concurrency, you should probably restart the check after the wait.

Comment: @Andreas Indeed, that's right. It's more than possible for the bot to fall over again.

Comment: @GBlodgett Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for. That works for now! :)

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this, is using a variable that will determine when to leave the loop. Your problem here, is that you also need to change your `for` loop for a `while` loop. Why is that? Because you don't know if the bot you just checked was moved or not. Also, the outer loop is unnecessarily, unless you wanted to recheck again. So the code would end looking something like this.

```
public static boolean checkUpright() throws InterruptedException {

    int counter = 0;
    while (counter <= theBots.length) { // bots = 2
        if (!theBots[i].isUpright()) {
            System.out.println("Please ensure I'm upright");
            Thread.sleep(500); 
        } else {
            counter ++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The context is not completely clear, but mixing logical control with user interaction might be the problem.  Perhaps this approach might work:

```
public static boolean checkUpright() throws InterruptedException {
    while (!areAllBotsUpright()) {
        System.out.println("Please ensure I'm upright");
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }
}

public static boolean areAllBotsUpright() {
   for (i = 0; i < bots; i++) {
       if (!theBots[i].isUpright()) {
           return false;     
       } 
   }

   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a list from array of bots , iterate over this list using iterator
if a particular bot is upright , remove it from this list using iterator.remove.
outer while will run until list is not empty.

```
public static boolean checkUpright()  {
    ArrayList<Bot> notUprightBots=   (ArrayList<Bot>) Arrays.asList(theBots);
    while (!notUprightBots.isEmpty()) {
        Iterator<Bot> iterator=notUprightBots.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            Bot bot=iterator.next();
            if (!bot.isUpright()) {
                System.out.println("Please ensure I'm upright");
                try{
                     Thread.sleep(500); 
                 }catch(InterruptedException  e){
                 } 

            }else {
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
    }
    return true;

}
```